# Path-dependent types in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
class Graph {
  case class Node(val a: Int)
  def createNodes = Node(5) :: Node(7) :: Nil
}

def test(g: Graph): List[g.Node] = g.createNodes
```

Then I do:

```
def test2(g: Graph) = {
  val nodes = test(g)
}
```

I was expecting for the compiler to track that `nodes` is of type `List[g.Node]`, but it seems to unable to do that and assigns its type to `List[Graph#Node]`. If I try type ascription, it still does not help: `val nodes: List[g.Node] = test(g)`

I feel like I'm missing something important behind path-dependent types in scala. How can I make `test(g)` return `List[g.Node]` and why scala needs path-dependent types converted to `A#B` if almost always we need `a.B`?

Comment: Might this be a compiler optimization? Your class Node does not relate to any particulars of 'g' and Scala might see that and generate a single class A#B. What if you add a reference to an attribute of `g`?

Comment: @DanielL. Unfortunately didn't help. I'm still seeing the same issue

Comment: @DanielL. Sorry, I panicked too early. That was IntellJ Idea error, compiler solves it correctly

Comment: no worries, it happens :-)

Comment: I recommend that you always verify this sort of thing using the command line Scala compiler or SBT ... IntelliJ is very unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh. It appears to be a bug of IntellJ Idea. It highlights it as an error, but the compiler resolves it correctly. Type ascription is not needed.